# Serializing a list throwing IO exception

Tags: java, serialization

I need some help.. I have been playing around with this forever and don't know what I'm missing, and I'm sure it's something small but I can't wrap my head around it. I have a binary search tree containing `Student` objects, and I am trying to convert the tree to a list, then serialize the list and when the program is ran again, deserialize that list and add each object back into the tree I'm using. I don't know why but my IOException keeps getting caught.

Here is where I am writing:

```
    private void saveRecord() {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "saving file...");
    System.out.println("Saving records:");
    ToListVisitor<Student> listVisit = new ToListVisitor<>();
    tree.inOrderTraversal(listVisit);

    System.out.println("List contains: " + listVisit.getList());


    try (ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(file))) {

        output.writeObject(listVisit.getList());//something with this line?

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("An error occured during serialization");
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        System.out.println(ioe.getStackTrace());
    }
}// end saveRecord
```

And I'm using a `ToListVisitor` to traverse through and add each object to a list, which appears to be working because when I run the line `System.out.println("List contains: " + listVisit.getList());` it displays all of the contents, and then it throws the error and nothing actually gets serialized.

Here is the visitor class:

```
public class ToListVisitor<E extends Comparable<? super E>>
implements Visitor<E> {

List<E> list = new ArrayList<E> ();

public ToListVisitor() {
  this.list = list;
}

public List<E> getList() {
  return list;
}

public void visit( BSTNode<E> node ) {
    System.out.println(node.element);
  list.add( node.element );
}


}
```

can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this???

Comment: *What* IOException? You're supposed to post the stack trace in your question. SO isn't a guessing game.

Comment: @EJP   } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("An error occured during serialization");
        System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        System.out.println(ioe.getStackTrace());
    }

Comment: I asked you for the stack trace, not how you print it. As a matter of fact you're doing it wrong. It should be 'ioe.printStackTrace()'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Student` needs to implement `Serializable`

Comment: Ah! Thank you I can't believe I missed that.. That was it!

Comment: @xTopShelfx Glad to hear it. Feel free to vote up and accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Serializable interface does not have any Methods. It may look like it is not needet or just an information addon. But internly java serialization (and other frameworks) use this interface to check wheather the class is serializable or not.